# Inverse function of a polynomial and its derivative

Tags: calculus, polynomials, inverse

I know it is a simple problem but I am having trouble. Here is what I have so far:

> Let $f(x) = x^5 + 2x^3 + x - 1$
>
> a) Find $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$

I have a) done. $f(1)$ is $3$ and $f'(1)$ is $12$

> b) Find $f^{-1}(3)$ and $(f^{-1})'(3)$

I need help with the first part. I think the way to find the inverse is to switch the $x$'s with $y$'s and then solve for $y$. But I am having trouble completing this. I have the following:
$$
x = y^5 + 2y^3 + y -1 
$$
$$
x - 1 = y^5 + 2y^3 + y
$$
What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Not that it helps in the slightest, but it wouldn't be $x - 1 = y^5 + 2y^3 + y$. It would be $x + 1 = y^5 + 2y^3 + y$. But this doesn't get you anywhere. yunone is right, you don't have to find the inverse explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need to find $f^{-1}$ explicitly. Remember that $f^{-1}(3)$ in this case is the number $x$ such that $f(x)=3$, and use what you've found in part (a).

For $(f^{-1})' (3)$, remember that by the inverse function theorem,
$$
(f^{-1})'(b)=\frac{1}{f'(a)}
$$
where $f(a)=b$, and again use what you've found in part (a).